# Classify velocity beams and dir sectors

Tags: r

I have a vector of velocities and another with directions.

I would like to classify my velocities by beams of [0-2,2-4,4-6....] and for each beam return the statistic summary by sectors. So for example:

**beam [2-4] m/s

```
sector        Mean          Sigma 
345-15:        3.12         0.49
15-45:         3.16         0.52
45-75:         3.10         0.45
...
```

for the moment, by using cut I have obtained:

> vel_bins: (0,5]   (0,5]   (0,5]   (0,5]   (0,5]   (0,5]
>
> (5,10]  (5,10]  (5,10]  (5,10]  (10,15] (10,15] (10,15]
>
> (10,15] (10,15] (10,15] (10,15]
>
> dir_bins:  (67.5,90] (67.5,90] (67.5,90] (67.5,90] (67.5,90]
>
> (67.5,90] (67.5,90] (67.5,90] (67.5,90] (45,67.5] (45,67.5]
>
> (45,67.5] (67.5,90] (67.5,90] (45,67.5]

And if I use `table(vel_bins,dir_bins)` I get:

```
> vel_dir_table
           vel_bins
dir_bins    (0,5] (5,10] (10,15] (15,20] (20,25] (25,30]

  (0,22.5]   1956   1122     196       3       0       0

  (22.5,45]  2435   2628     618      62       2       0

  (45,67.5]  2800   7196    6744     422       5       0

  (67.5,90]  2970   5806    3422      16       0       0

  (90,112]   2908   2156     381       0       0       0

  (112,135]  2031   1221      55       0       0       0

  (135,158]  1990   1271     172       8       0       0

  (158,180]  1966   1397     274      10       1       0

  (180,202]  2272   1509     623      57      13       3

  (202,225]  2423   2611    2022     407      26       9

  (225,248]  3605   4963    1782     451      64      16

  (248,270]  2889   6480    2804     289      21       9

  (270,292]  2113   3610    2117     126      11       6

  (292,315]  1811   2268     996     102      14       0

  (315,338]  2022   1900    1044      69      28       0

  (338,360]  1769   1150     258       4       0       0
```

But I don't know how to follow. If anyone would help would be very greatful!
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can understand my code:

```
# max values, velocity v and position x
max.v <- 12
max.x <- 100

# number of segments
l.v <- 5
l.x <- 4

# random data
data <- data.frame(x=runif(1000, 0, max.x + 3), v=runif(1000, 0, max.v + 3))

dir.v <- seq(0, max.v, length=l.v)
dir.x <- seq(0, max.x, length=l.x)

# create empty matrix of lists
m <- matrix(list(NA), l.x, l.v)

# sort x and v
pos.x <- floor(data$x/max.x * (l.x-1)) + 1
pos.v <- floor(data$v/max.v * (l.v-1)) + 1

# if >l.x then it is put in the last one
pos.x[pos.x>=l.x] <- l.x
pos.v[pos.v>=l.v] <- l.v

# sort
for(i in 1:length(data$v)){
  m[[pos.x[i], pos.v[i]]] <- append(m[[pos.x[i], pos.v[i]]], data$v[i])
}

# write to file
fileConn<-file("output.txt", open="w")
for(i in 1:l.v){
  write(paste("v", "x", "mean(v)", "\t\tsd(v)", sep="\t"), file=fileConn, append=TRUE)
  for(j in 1:l.x){
    write(paste(dir.v[i], round(dir.x[j],1), mean(m[[j,i]], na.rm = TRUE), sd(m[[j,i]], na.rm=TRUE), sep="\t"), file=fileConn, append=TRUE)
  }
  write("\n", file=fileConn, append=TRUE)
}
close(fileConn)
```

Hope that helps.